# Laravel folder not being pushed from CodeStar to Deploy

Tags: laravel, aws-code-deploy, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit, aws-codestar

I have a pipeline in place on AWS for a Laravel application. When I commit changes to master, they all go except one folder. The "Modules" folder. Every other file and folder updates and even when I check CodeCommit, the folder is there. However, once I ssh into the instance, its nowhere to be found. All other files are timestamped as being deployed. The folder is not in a GitIgnore.

Long story short, the master branch is being updated and the offending folder is there. The deployment is triggered but the folder is missing from the instance. I'm truly stumped.

**What I've tried:**

1 - Tried to create other folders and commit them (with files)
2 - Tried to add root to ec2-user group in case of write issue.
3 - Checked AWS log file on instance and on AWS console.
4 - Checked all Git files (which was unnessacery as the folders are on GitCommit)

**Update:** So the issue is limited to any new folder created in the root directory. Any new folders will commit and trigger a deploy but the new folders will not be on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this issue is to edit the `appspec.yml` file in the root directory and add your folder in there as it will not be deployed, even if the folder is in your Git repo.

*Like so:*
[image: Add a source and destination like so.]